# Looking for a simple graphical component for Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am looking for a graphical component in Delphi winch have such features:

- allows to paint text in different font types, sizes and colors
- allows to select previously drawn text and copy it
- paints images on a given coords, gif support would be nice
- its very fast in terms of CPU usage

I need this component as a main chat window. I don't want to use it as a text editor.

I've tried two solutions so far:

- TVirtualStringTree
- THtml

Currently I am using THtml. It performs quite nice but it is a bit to slow due to two facts:

- It supports many features which are not necessary in my case
- Each time I want to add some content to it, I must reload the whole content

I really don't want to go into its sources and modify them until I have no other choice. So maybe someone of you knows some nice lightweight component which I can use instead?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [TRichView](http://www.trichview.com/). It's derived from TCustomControl so no external dependencies. It's third party commercial component, but a very good one. Skype Win client uses it.

Comment: Thanks Mihaela. I was few times on this site and always tought that this is not for me... But maybe I was wrong, so I am give it a try.

Comment: Do try it. It's really very powerful. Once I used it as a reporting "engine". You can draw anything on TRichView, tables, images. But it is also a full blown rich editor , like mini Word.
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

What about a `TRichEdit`? Most of the things you mention should be easiliby possible with this component.

Concering the insertion of a bitmap, see this [article on Delphi 3000](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1819.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Smasher. I've tried with adding bitmap and it works. However I don't feel that TRichEdit is exactly what I want. It has this blinking cursor (since its a text editor) and allows me to add only a bitmap. Perhaps this two issues can be solved but it is not as straightforward as I would like to. But if noone else gives me a better clue I will mark it as answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find something that fits your needs EXACTLY. Concerning the cursor: http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0703_5.htm. And GIF components are definitely available.

Comment: I've found that link: http://www.mombu.com/programming/html/t-how-to-add-gif-picture-to-memo-or-richedit-in-bcb-801097.html
but as I said earlier. It is not straightforward....

Comment: You could use `TGIFImage` to convert it to a bitmap.

Comment: BTW: I don'T want to talk you into using `TRichEdit`. I just think that the points you mention are solvable. If you find a better component - wonderful!

Comment: It's ok Smasher, I just hope for some kind of advice. You see, when I convert GIF into bitmap I will lose probably a transparency and I will lose for sure an animation...

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using TWebBrowser?

At least it ticks all your boxes...

Comment: Thamks for answer but I am afraid it will work the same as THtml: Each time I want to add some content to it, I must reload the whole content.

Comment: That depends on how to modify the content. You can definitely add content without refreshing the whole content, by accessing the DOM directly, or by calling JavaScript that does it for you.

Comment: Indeed Wouter, I haven't tought about it.

Comment: Back when this was written (2011), this basically meant interacting with Internet Explorer. Nowadays (2023) TWebBrowser also wraps the Chromium-based Edge browser. Much better. Fast, and full of features, even hardware accelerated.